# Android Wear without google play services?

Tags: android, google-play-services, wear-os

I'm not a very big fan of Google play services. I don't know what they do under the hood and they are not open source.

I would still like to connect my app with Android Wear to have a basic communication without the google lib. Is it possible?

Comment: There may be a way to do this, but to be honest, you would be better off using Google Play Services. It's the easiest way of using Google's services within your app.

Comment: Play services are not an option for my app and users :)

Answer (score 1):

Your phone has bluetooth, your wear device has bluetooth, you can connect them using the standard bluetooth api. Or, as both devices have wifi, you can make them connect through a server. You have to write your own server for that, i.e. your own "Play".